# Twitter to Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have done much searching but not able to find a solution.

Trying to get my Twitter to Facebook feed setup but getting this error:

"Facebook reported an error. The error has been reported to our engineering team. Please try again as it might be a temporary problem"

From what I can gather it may have something to do with an old account that has been deleted, but I have no idea how to resolve this and nor do a lot of other people.

Comment: If this is a programming question, please show us your code. If this is not a programming question, it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

First up: this is not a programming question since it's not related to the Twitter API but to the Twitter interface. Therefore, it's actually to be regarded as *"Off-Topic"*.

**To give you a helping hand nevertheless:**

What you are describing is a known bug Twitter bug. Check https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=110412992466716 and https://dev.twitter.com/issues/998

The problem comes up when your Twitter account was previously connected to another Facebook account that you deleted/deactivated without removing the Twitter app first. Now that you try to connect to a new Facebook account, Twitter still tries to authorize using the old credentials of that other account.

Currently, your only hope is to ask Twitter to manually remove the old account credentials from your Twitter profile's backend. From what I've been reading, Twitter frequently fails being cooperative in that point... you can only ask and hope someone at Twitter is able and willing to manually correct their bug.